# Android Youtube API V3 cast exception when Release+Proguard ON

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have an Android app that utilises the [youtube.search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list+) method. This application works fine when in "Debug" and when proguard is disabled in "Release".

When proguard is turned on (minifyEnabled true), I get the following exception when i iterate a list of the SearchResult class

```
com.google.api.client.util.ArrayMap cannot be cast to 
com.google.api.services.youtube.model.SearchResult
```

I set the following rules in proguard-rules (according to the advice in the comments in another question "[android proguard makes the youtube api oauth disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731859/android-proguard-makes-the-youtube-api-oauth-disabled)")

```
-keep class com.google.api.** {
    *;
}
```

The following is the code segment that retrieves the List <  SearchResult > . This part works fine (searchResultList.size() returns 25).

```
youtube = new Youtube.builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                              new JacksonFactory(),
                              request->{})
                     .setApplicationName("youtube-search")
                     .build();

search = youtube.search()
                .list("id,snippet")
                .setKey(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY)
                .setQ("test") 
                .setMaxResults(25);

 SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();

List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems()
```

The following loop will cause the error to occur

```
for (SearchResult r: searchResultList){ 
   // program throws exception only in "RELEASE" with proguard on.
}
```

Any insights is appreciated.

Comment: For me I was having -keepattributes Signature but was missing -keep class com.google.api.** {
    *;
}

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as you do while building with proguard, I add this line in my proguard rule :

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

and it works for me.

From [proguard official site](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html) :

> For example, you should at least keep the Exceptions, InnerClasses, and Signature attributes when processing a library.